# How to: Strapi GraphQL mutation with dynamic zones/component

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am trying to create a mutation for Strapi that creates/edits dynamic zones. Dynamic zones in Strapi are union types. How does one do a GraphQL **mutation** with **dynamic zones**?

**To be exact. What should be the content here?**

> input: {data: {inhalt: [{text: "hallo"}]}}

In the example below there is a single component named ***impressum***. ***Inhalt*** is the dynamic zone. It contains different components: **ComponentPageText, ComponentPageInformation** and **ComponentPageArticle**.

This mutation

```
mutation {
  updateImpressum(input: {data: {inhalt: [{text: "hallo"}]}}) {
    impressum {
      inhalt {
        __typename
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns

> Expected type ImpressumInhaltDynamicZoneInput!, found {text: \"hallo\"}; Component not found. expected one of: ComponentPageText, ComponentPageInformation, ComponentPageArticle

This returns the same error

```
mutation {
  updateImpressum(input: {data: {inhalt: [{ComponentPageText: {text: "hallo"}}]}}) {
    impressum {
      inhalt {
        __typename
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Schema introspection returns

```
{
  "name": "ComponentPageText",
  "kind": "OBJECT"
}
```

**STRUCTURE** (added after comment)

> impressum => inhalt => [page.text, page.information,
>   page.article]

corresponds to

> *single type => dynamic zone => [components]*

Fields in components

> **page.text**: text
>   **page.information**: title, text, image
>   **page.article**: relation to collection type - article

**SCHEMA INTROSPECTION**

```
{
  "name": "updateImpressum",
  "__typename": "__Field",
  "description": "",
  "args": [
    {
      "name": "input",
      "description": "",
      "__typename": "__InputValue",
      "type": {
        "kind": "INPUT_OBJECT",
        "name": "updateImpressumInput",
        "possibleTypes": null,
        "interfaces": null,
        "inputFields": [
          {
            "name": "data",
            "description": "",
            "__typename": "__InputValue"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you please share your compo and content type structure.

Comment: @JimLAURIE I added the structure above in the question. Was this what you meant? Do you need any more information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how to mutate a dynamic zone in Strapi. In my case, I have a collection called Tests and a dynamic zone called New Question that is under a group called questions-group:

```
mutation {
 createTest(input:{ data:{
  title:"Test Title Here"
  questions: [
     {
      __typename: "ComponentQuestionsGroupNewQuestion"
      __component: "questions-group.new-question"
      title:"What is 4 + 20?"
      correct_answer: "24"
      wrong_answer: "420"
    }
  ]
  }}) {
    test {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

You have to provide `__typename:` and `__component:` inside the dynamic zone clause.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot for your answer! I am sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Now (I'm usign Strapi 3.6.2 with MongoDB) you don't have to include `__component` anymore. You can just provide `__typename` and it will work correctly.

Comment: Life saver! I don't understand why there's no docu about this on the main site

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this to work with components:

```
mutation($text: String!) {
  updateImpressum {
    impressum {
      inhalt {
        __typename
        ... on MyComponentName {
            text: $text
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Tip: use the /graphql client to autocomplete component types by typing
>   "... on "
>
> Tip2: Use fragments

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but what I cannot figure out is not how to query after doing the mutation but the mutation itself. Meaning this string "updateImpressum(input: {data: {inhalt: [{text: "hallo"}]}})". I am sorry if I did not express this clearly in my question.